# Can a Horizon Walker ranger teleport before making their additional attack with the Distant Strike feature?

Tags: dnd-5e, class-feature, attack, ranger, teleportation

The [Horizon Walker](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#HorizonWalker) ranger subclass from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything* gains the [Distant Strike](https://www.dndbeyond.com/classes/ranger#DistantStrike-726) feature at 11th level (p. 43):

> At 11th level, you gain the ability to pass between the planes in the blink of an eye. When you take the Attack action, you can teleport up to 10 feet before each attack to an unoccupied space you can see. If you attack at least two different creatures with the action, you can make one additional attack with it
>   against a third creature.

If you attack two different creatures, and gain the one additional attack against a third creature, could you also teleport before that third attack?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Yes

> you can make one additional attack **with it**

(emphasis added)

the extra attack is also part of your Attack action, and thus:

> you can teleport up to 10 feet before each attack

applies to it.